# Add list item in querystring in URL, ID needs to be hidden

Tags: url, hyperlink, query-string

Trying to add a list item, specifically the ID into a url in the DispForm.aspx.  The customer does not want the ID displayed.  I got the link in the display form, I figured out how to split out the ID: I just don't know how to add it or append it to the URL as a querystring.  Here is what I have...again, I got the ID, I just need to add it to the .aspx?ID=XX portion in the a href:

```
<script src="/siteassets/jsLib/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var a=window.location.href;
    var b=a.split("?")[1];
    var c=b.split("&")[0];
    var d=c.split("=")[1];
    //how do I get "d" in "XX" below?    
</script>
<a href="/siteassets/printpreview.aspx?ID=XX" target="_blank">Print Preview</a>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to split the url in Sharepoint. Just use the Sharepoint built-in function `var urlParam = GetUrlKeyValue("NAME_OF_YOUR_URL_PARAMETER")` supposing that the page url is something like `page.aspx?NAME_OF_YOUR_URL_PARAMETER=1`.
Then in your HTML you can build a link like:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.location='/siteassets/printpreview.aspx?ID=' + urlParam" target="_blank">Print Preview</a>
```

Comment: Thanks @steve-t.  Your solution worked for me.  I did have to change the "a href" to a document.write .  For some reason the "a href" opened a separate tab but the focus was on the originating page and not the "target_blank" page.